# Consuming Spirulina with Wheat Grass

Tags: diet, nutrition, protein, health, food

I maintain a pretty healthy life style and I exercise 6 days a week as follows:

I run at least 3 days every week totaling to 20Kms.  And, on other days I do PullUps,Push UPs, sun salutes and light weights.

I have been regularly drinking Wheat Grass powder with water for the last 4-6 months on an empty stomach early in morning, and, I have seen positive effect in my digestion and energy levels.
I recently also read about the benefits of Spirulina and I am planning to get it in tablet form. I am a vegetarian.

But, here are my concerns...

Is it advisable to consume both of them together (Spirulina & Wheat Grass) ? 
Or, should I alternate between both of them? For example, for some length of time, consume one of them and then switch to another and keep on alternating between both of them?  Or, can I consume both of them during different periods of days?

I am worried if consuming both of them together can have any negative effects .

Answer (score 1):

Judging the nutritional facts i would say you are safe. 
I have taken multivitamins that have the daily needed value way over exceeded and been just fine(if that is what you are worried about)

What ever diet plan you read, it always says "As many greens as you want".
At the end of the day you just have to test it yourself because everyone responds to different things differently because no one is like you.

If you feel sick,bloated...stop, other than that, you are safe.